# Combobox ignores autoLoad [Extjs]

Tags: extjs

i'm trying to make that a combo load the items (dataStore) with **AutoLoad: true**, but, i don't know if i'm doing this right. I'm a little newbie with *Extjs*, so, don't be rude, please hehe

here's the code!

```
items: [{
                xtype: 'form',
                padding: 20,
                name: 'formReplyParameters',
                layout: 'anchor',
                fieldDefaults: {
                    msgTarget: 'under',
                    labelAlign: 'top'
                },
                defaults: {
                    padding: 10
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                    name: 'interactive',
                    inputValue: true,
                    fieldLabel: 'Interactive',
                    anchor: '100%'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'timeResponse',
                    fieldLabel: 'Time response',
                    anchor: '100%'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'combobox',
                    fieldLabel: 'Alert channel',
                    name: 'uuidResponseParameterType',
                    queryMode: 'local',
                    store: new Ext.data.Store({
                        fields: [{
                            name: 'description',
                            type: 'string'
                        }, {
                            name: 'name',
                            type: 'string'
                        }, {
                            name: 'uuid',
                            type: 'string'
                        }],
                        autoLoad: true,
                        hideTrigger: true,
                        minChars: 1,
                        triggerAction: 'query',
                        typeAhead: true,
                        proxy: {
                            type: 'ajax',
                            url: "../blabla",
                            actionMethods: {
                                create: "POST",
                                read: "POST",
                                update: "POST",
                                destroy: "POST"
                            },
                            extraParams: {
                                action: "catalog",
                                catalog: "parametersType",
                                params: JSON.stringify({
                                    uuidToken: Ext.connectionToken
                                })
                            },
                            reader: {
                                type: 'json',
                                root: 'List'
                            },
                            listeners: {
                                exception: function(proxy, response, operation, eOpts) {
                                    var responseArray = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
                                    Ext.Notify.msg(responseArray.message, {
                                        layout: "bottomright",
                                        delay: 5000,
                                        type: "error"
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }),
                    anchor: '100%',
                    typeAhead: true,
                    triggerAction: 'all',
                    valueField: 'uuid',
                    displayField: 'description',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    listeners: {
                        change: function (combo, value) {
                            var type = combo.valueModels[0].data.name;
                            var channel = me.down('[name="uuidChanel"]');
                            channel.clearValue();
                            var channelStore = new Ext.data.Store({
                                fields: [{
                                    name: 'description',
                                    type: 'string'
                                }, {
                                    name: 'name',
                                    type: 'string'
                                }, {
                                    name: 'uuid',
                                    type: 'string'
                                }],
                                autoLoad: true,
                                hideTrigger: true,
                                minChars: 1,
                                triggerAction: 'query',
                                typeAhead: true,
                                proxy: {
                                    type: 'ajax',
                                    url: "../handler/custom/customEvent.ashx",
                                    extraParams: {
                                        action: "catalog",
                                        catalog: type,
                                        params: JSON.stringify({
                                            uuidToken: Ext.connectionToken
                                        })
                                    },
                                    reader: {
                                        type: 'json',
                                        root: 'list'
                                    },
                                    listeners: {
                                        exception: function(proxy, response, operation, eOpts) {
                                            var responseArray = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
                                            Ext.Notify.msg(responseArray.message, {
                                                layout: "bottomright",
                                                delay: 5000,
                                                type: "error"
                                            });
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            channelStore.load();
                            channel.bindStore(channelStore);
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    xtype: 'combo',
                    name: 'uuidChanel',
                    fieldLabel: 'Channel',
                    valueField: 'uuid',
                    displayField: 'description',
                    anchor: '100%',
                    store: null,
                    allowBlank: false
                }]
            }]
```

The problem is in the combo: **uuidChannel**
if anyone can help, thanks a lot!

Comment: Combo with `name: 'uuidChanel'` configured with `store: null`...

Comment: @SergeyNovikov trust me, i tried several times without 'store: null', and nothing happens.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didnt check whole code carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly you think that `autoLoad: true` doest work? Because when you try to open last combobox picker its still loading?

I think your problem is that new store created every time combo `name: 'uuidResponseParameterType'` `change` event trigger and store `autoLoad: true` means that

> store's load method is automatically called after creation

You have to create store just once and load (or filter locally) it with new `extraParams` on combo `change` event.

Comment: Woops, i really don't understand what do u mean hehe, but, i fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that (stupid)

> channel.clearValue();

this field was doing all the problem. this "clearValue" was there because I believed that deleting the data of "uuid", it was returning me the new data with the "bind" to the bottom

```
channelStore.load();
channel.bindStore(channelStore); <<<
```

So, I think i put the new data, but this "clearValue", just was erasing the data with the "bind" I had down. So, i just elimite that `channel.clearValue();` , and that's solves the problem! :)

Comment: Now Im completely confused what actually you means under "combobox ignores autoLoad" because in your code sample `clearValue()` has nothing to do with store `autoLoad`... Can you, please, update your question so it reflect your actual issue? Later Ill update my answer to show you real issues with your code.

Comment: well @SergeyNovikov, first, sorry pal, for answer you too late. Let me explain you, I have 2 `combobox`, and the second, do not has data, but the first has data, so I have a `change` function to change the data that has been passed for the first combo to the second, and that `autoLoad: true`, should to load the data that has been passed for the first `combo` to the  second, but, like i said before, the `clearValue();` has been erased my data (the data of the first `combo` when this passed to the second). I don't know if you understand, but that's it!